# Solidity function // for loop

Tags: solidity, transactions, javascript, testing, confirmations

Im calling in a for loop a set function in js, but it stops/crashes after the 2nd or 3rd loop. I want to run it for about 5000 times, without losing queue.
Is it possible?
How can i implement this?
I believe that somehow the function should w8 for the confirmation of the previous transaction to move on to the next one.(?)
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you show your js code ? it is unclear if you are looking for a web3 / ethers solutions amongst others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I clearly did not understood the question if you are using for loop in solidity or normally making use of  web3 api.
But I guess that you want loop to be waited until the transaction get complete and then new iteration of the same. You should not use for loop as it will hang the browser. Remix ide gives very bad experience with loops
Instead use  in js

```
function loop(i,cond,update,body){
if(cond(i))
{
    body(i)
    //do anything with I 
     setTimeout(arguments.callee,0,update(i),cond,update,body)
}}
```

Where i is the first number to be iterated, cond is the condition function like   **i=>i<5000** and body is function which should be inside the body of for loop like i=>console.log(i)

ex:-

```
for(let i=-4;i<5000;i+=2){console.log(i+5)
```

we do like this in this function

```
loop(-4,i=>i<5000,i=>i+2,i=>console.log(i+5))
```

if after this your browser hangs  then it means you are doing heavy work synchronously, try changing it to asynchronous